# How can I send event for all mounted tags?

Tags: event-handling, observable, riot.js

riot.js 2.2

By guides on official site of riot.js I have to call something like

```
tag.trigger('event_name')
```

where the `tag` is the instance of certain listener.

But what must i do to trigger event for all tags?
Has riot.js any implementation for this issue or I have to resolve it manually(by keeping all listeners instances)?

Comment: My simple vision of the solution https://github.com/d0as8/RiotBus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riot has no implementation of keeping references to all event listeners. So, if you want to execute `trigger` on them directly, you'll have to implement it yourself.

However, I would recommend to use another solution for notifying multiple event listeners.

If you want to let know multiple tags that an event has occured, you can use a shared observable and handle events on this observable. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435078/riotjs-how-to-pass-events-between-subtags-using-observable-pattern/32096712#32096712). This way, you don't need to keep refereneces to all event listeners, instead, event listeners need to keep reference to single observable ('event aggregator').

You can also try [RiotControl](https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl) as a shared observable.

Comment: Thanks. It is what i need