# RiotJs: communication with a tag instance

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm just beginning to learn riotJS and not able to figure out how communication between tag (instances) is done. I created a simple example. Lets say I have the following tag:

```
<warning-message>
    <div>{ warning_message }</div>

    <script>
        this.warning_message = "Default warning!";
        this.on('updateMessage', function(message){
            this.warning_message = message;
        });
    </script>
</warning-message>
```

I think I can use `tagInstance.trigger('updateMessage', someData)` to tell the tag instance to update the message but how do I get a reference to the tag instance from within my main js file so that i can call the trigger() method on it? I think the mount() method returns an instance but what if you want to obtain a reference later?

Comment: Did you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435078/riotjs-how-to-pass-events-between-subtags-using-observable-pattern/32096712#32096712

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a reference for the tag instance you have to do this. tags will be an array with the tags.

```
  riot.compile(function() {
    tags = riot.mount('*')
    console.log('root tag',tags[0])
  })
```

If you want to access children, let say that vader is parent tag, leia and luke children tag

```
  riot.compile(function() {
    tags = riot.mount('*')
    console.log('parent',tags[0])
    console.log('children',tags[0].tags)
    console.log('first child by name',tags[0].tags.luke)
    console.log('second child by hash',tags[0].tags['leia'])
  })
```

But I will recommend the observable pattern for tag communication.  It´s easy

1) Create a store.js file

```
var Store = function(){
  riot.observable(this)
}
```

2)In the index add it to the global riot object, so it will be accessible anywhere

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      riot.store = new Store()
      riot.mount('*')   
    </script>
```

3)Then in any tag you can have:

```
riot.store.on('hello', function(greeting) {
  self.hi = greeting
  self.update()
})
```

4)And in other tag have:

```
riot.store.trigger('hello', 'Hello, from Leia')
```

So you communicate using the riot.store global object, sending and receiving messages

Live example http://plnkr.co/edit/QWXx3UJWYgG6cRo5OCVY?p=preview

In your case, using the riot.store is the same, probably you will need to use self to not lose the context reference

```
<script>
    var self = this
    this.warning_message = "Default warning!";
    riot.store.on('updateMessage', function(message){
        self.warning_message = message;
    });
</script>
```

And then from any other tag call

```
riot.store.trigger('updateMessage', 'Hello')
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use global store, take a look at [RiotComponent](https://github.com/NawaMan/RiotComponent). It enable communication between elements in an intuitive way.

It basically allows methods, listenable properties and event to be added to the element so the parent element can use those.